# Rshiny Table collapse text overflow

Tags: css, r, rstudio, shiny

How do we pass CSS arguments `text-overflow: ellipsis` or other arguments to renderDataTable in R shiny ? I have uneven text description in columns, by Autowidth the rows and columns are expanded based on the contents in respective cell.

I would like to be able to input "ellipsis", for user to be able to expand the cell to read text. Below is my server.r code. I tried to use the eg, explained in http://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html. However, could not get what I am looking for. Appreciate if any inputs , suggestions are provided.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. 
The problem was with improper way I passed the arguments. The correct way is below.

```
  output$PM_output <- DT::renderDataTable(
    expr =  DT::datatable(data.frame.eg),
                          class   = 'cell-border stripe compact hover',
                          escape  = F, selection = 'multiple',
                          options = list(
                            autoWidth  = T,
                            LengthMenu = c(5, 30, 50),
                            columnDefs = list(list(
                              targets  = 6,
                              render   = JS(
                                "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
                                "return type === 'display' && data.length > 100 ?",                                    "'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' +
                                data.substr(0, 100) + '...</span>' : data;", "}"))),
                              pageLength = 1, server = T)))
```